# Adding functionality to view in admin mode

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am developing a website, and I need to give 'admin' user CRUD(create/read/update/delete) functionality.
I am developing using php and CodeIgniter.
I have a view called gallery.php which display thumbnails, as grid.
each thumbnail have 2 buttons below(edit,delete) the thumbnail.
I want...
admin user - need to see those 2 buttons.
all rest wont see those 2 buttons.

I what to use the same view(not to duplicate it...) and just hide those buttons in case user is not admin.
What do I need to do? passing $is_admin to gallery.php seems to be a little ugly i guess.

Thx

Comment: how do you identify its an admin...through server `localhost` or do you have specific login for it?

Comment: You can always swap out the entire template: have one template with buttons and one without. That way you will have to perform the "is admin" check only once.

Comment: users url: /gallery admin url: /admin/gallery. i don't want to manage 2 template because if i found bug/need to add more stuff, i will have to update 2 templates

Comment: You have two choices either swap out the entire template as suggested by @tereško or pass $is_admin to gallery.php.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

when you login check its admin or not than store into session variable.
no need to create same page again & again ..
no need to pass variable into url..
just use session variable for checking its admin or not.